# Cross-language bi-directional Client-Server communication methodology?

Tags: client-server, communication, synchronous, cross-language

I am making a turn-based card game that will have clients, a lobby server and a game server. What methologies are there that are both cross-language and bi-directional (e.g. client request -> server server response-> client, as well as server request-> client client response -> server)?

I have looked into JMS but believe it is too heavyweight for my needs (this program will just be small scale, and I don't think the complexities make this solution suitable). I have briefly looked into REST but I believe that wouldn't fit the bi-directional requirement. Of course, there is RMI but I would like to be able to develop clients in C++ and other languages as another learning exercise.

If I'm honest, I'm at a bit of loss because I don't want to use JMS as I think it is too complex for this, but I don't think just using TCP sockets and say using a basic XML based protocol for the messages will provide a good structure of communication for the program.

Answer (score 2):

The research lab that I do some work with develops a system called "Object Oriented Distributed Semantic Services."

We leverage some work that we do with cross-language serialization to allow you to write clients/servers in different languages, and the underlying messages to be a format that be serialized and deserialized by clients/servers regardless of their implementation language.

Right now we mostly support Java/ObjectiveC. You can take a look at the chat room tutorial, which should give you a basic idea of how requests / responses work.

http://ecologylab.net/research/simplGuide/oodss/index.html

OODSS is designed to work well for game scenarios... the system was originally written to support a game one of the researchers in our lab was working on. The original paper on OODSS discusses the development of a game from the ground up. That may work out well for you: http://ecologylab.net/technicalReports/oodss_TR_10_01.pdf

You could apply a similar idea to allow for multiple clients in languages that aren't supported yet. (you may have to write some serialization/deserialization code on your own, to start.)

Good luck! Hope that helps!